# Nvidia GeForce 9600m GT not enabled

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am at Sony VGN-AW220j , I’ve installed Ubuntu 12.10 recently with Unity, i am facing problem with my Graphics card.
i tried to install NVIDIA Current, NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.19
but no result.

when I am typing

`lspci| grep VGA`

I get

```
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9600M GT] (rev a1)
```

but when go to system setting> Details. I found my Graphic card with no driver installed or unknown.

any help please

*Thanks in Advance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GPU's model can be shown by this package `mesa-utils`**

type this in your terminal `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

*Do you have only nvidia's GPU? (comment below please so I can edit this post! ;) )
If you have switchable GPUs, and are using bublebee I recommend do not try to change anything in your system. If not try and install `mesa-utils`*

*and also see this http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-install-nvidia-2750907-driver-in.html*

Comment: I am not sure, but when i type <code>lspci -vmk | grep -A 8 -B 2 VGA

I get this

Device: 01:00.0
Class: VGA compatible controller
Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Device: G96 [GeForce 9600M GT]
SVendor: Sony Corporation
SDevice: Device 9040
Rev: a1
Driver: nvidia
Module: nvidia_current
Module: nouveau

If you need anything else please let me know.

Comment: well then if your graphics works well there is no problem. I mean if your resolution is okey and does not run in low graphic mode your nvidia's GPU is working. You should only search and find how to show your GPU's name in the system details.

Comment: Yes My Resolution is okay , the only thing I am trying to do is to get my model number in system details, and also to use Nvidia Control Panel, Like I used in Windows OS, if it's Possible, 

Thanks for your Quick reply, I really appreciated

Comment: what can you do on nvidia control panel in windows?

Comment: Like applying all NVIDIA Setting to my Desktop and Videos, Enable or Disable Physics, anyhow not a big deal, 
Now I get My GPUs Model Number In System Details.
 Using <b> mesa-utils</b> 
Thanks

Comment: as I said ;) I update above post ;)

Comment: if you get your answer please provide us a feedback, so other users can use your answer. If this answer is your solution click on the "tick" at the left side::Thanks